# How to get Underscore in textbox content in MVC in Print preview mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have printing textbox, labels and dropdown values on print preview page. Here I've attached Codepen link as well as code what I have done yet.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div class="container no-print">
    <div class="row" id="DivDate">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="text" name="CreatedDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="DivDoc">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">
                            Respected Dr.
                        </label>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-8">
              <input type="text" name="txtDoctor" placeholder="Doctor Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="DivData">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2">
                            Referring
                        </label>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
              <select name="ddlGender" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8">
              <input type="text" name="txtPatient" placeholder="Patient Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                            to you for the favour of your kind consultation of
                        </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-6">
              <select name="ddlGender" class="form-control">
                                <option value="his">his</option>
                                <option value="her">her</option>
                            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <select name="ddlOption" class="form-control">
                                <option value="C/O">C/O</option>
                            </select>.
            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                            Please do the needful to evaluate the case and treat
                        </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-6">
              <select name="ddlGender" class="form-control">
                                <option value="him">him</option>
                                <option value="her">her</option>
                            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                            accordingly.
                        </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="DivFooter">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="pull-right text-center">
            <label>
                            Regards and Respect<br />
                            from<br />
                            Dr. Jayesh Hathi
                        </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="BtnSave" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="button" value="Print" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-block btn-default" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="print">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="pull-right" id="PrintDate">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group" id="PrintDoc">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group" id="PrintData">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="pull-right text-center">
            <label>
                            Regards and Respect<br />
                            from<br />
                            Dr. Jayesh Hathi
                        </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

And Jquery:

```
$("#BtnSave").click(function() {
  var values1 = [];
  $('#DivDate').find("input,select,label").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'button') return true;
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      values1.push($(this).val().trim());
    } else {
      values1.push($(this).text().trim());
    }
  });
  $("#PrintDate").text(values1.join(" "));

  var values2 = [];
  $('#DivDoc').find("input,select,label").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'button') return true;
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      values2.push($(this).val().trim());
    } else {
      values2.push($(this).text().trim());
    }
  });
  $("#PrintDoc").text(values2.join(" "));

  var values3 = [];
  $('#DivData').find("input,select,label").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'button') return true;
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      values3.push($(this).val().trim());
    } else {
      values3.push($(this).text().trim());
    }
  });
  $("#PrintData").text(values3.join(" "));

  window.print();

});
```

CodePen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmjmBr

I want underscore under input text like doctorname and patient name. Can I add HTML any how in preview mode?

As I am getting value of all input in array and joining it, I don't think I can save HTML code in array.

I've attached Image for better clarification
[image]

Comment: for clarification... do you want to change the cursor for your input field to underscore?

Comment: I've attached image what exactly I want. I want underscore under each input box value

Comment: You can't underline only a portion of the text with TextBox, you must use RichTextBox...

Comment: If I use RichTechBox, Do I get HTML tags in array with this method? or should I find any alternate way to do so?

Comment: You should probably use an alternative way to do so, but you could try.

Comment: You could also instead of a textbox use a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` which basically does the same but you can use html tags inside it